# Concatenate two fields in select list (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, selectlist

I use a viewbag to create a select list and I want to Show two fields concatenated together.  However, it is crashing on my view.  Here is the viewbag code:

```
ViewBag.PackageId = new SelectList(db.Packages.Where(p => p.status == "A"), "u_package_id", "u_package_id" + "'-'" + "package_nme");
```

Comment: What if any error message are you getting? Is there a stack trace you can show?

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd parameters of the `SelectList` constructor are strings that must match the names of properties in your model (in your case they don't hence the error). Instead generate a collection of `SelectListItem` where you set `Value` and `Text` properties

Comment: Are the unpaired single quotes in play here? `"'-'"`
@StephenMuecke - and you reflected my next comment theme. :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I was guessing that is the issue. However, how would I do that? do you have a simple example?

Comment: Sure, will add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
ViewBag.PackageId = db.Packages.Where(p => p.status == "A")
    .Select(p => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = p.u_package_id + "-" + p.package_nme,
        Value = p.u_package_id
    };
```

Comment: what if I need to assign a default value of the select list item, How would I achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd and 3rd parameters of the SelectList constructor are strings that must match the names of properties in your model (in your case your don't have a property named `"u_package_id-package_nme"` hence the error).

In the controller, generate a collection of `SelectListItem`

```
ViewBag.PackageList = db.Packages.Where(p => p.status == "A").Select(p => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = p.u_package_id, // may need .ToString() depending on the property type
    Text = string.Format("{0}-{1}", p.u_package_id, p.package_nme)
}
```

Side note: Suggest you name your properties to reflect what they are (i.e. its a collection of items, not an ID so `PackageList`, not `PackageId`) and this would be necessary anyway if the model your binding to contains a property named `PackageId`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to deramko, I have my answer.  He was 99% of the way there.  Here is the final code:

```
ViewBag.PackageId = db.Packages.Where(p => p.status == "A")
      .Select(p => new SelectListItem
      {
             Text = p.u_package_id + "-" + p.package_nme,
             Value = p.u_package_id.ToString()
      });
```